Don't truncate NavigationSplitView's sidebar text in macOS app
I got a basic macOS app with a sidebar which contains (long) text. How can I make sure the text is not truncated, at least not when starting the app?
I got this code:
struct ContentView: View {
    enum ContentType: CaseIterable, Identifiable, Equatable {
        case a, b
        
        var id: Self {
            self
        }
    }
    
    @State var contentType = ContentType.a
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(ContentType.allCases, selection: $contentType) { value in
                NavigationLink(value: value) {
                    Image(systemName: "info")
                    Text("Some Long Text")
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            
        }
    }
}

I tried a GeometryReader but it doesn't work. Probably because the width is the same as the truncated size. Calculating the size based on the font is possible, but it looks so difficult for such a simple task.
This is how it looks when starting up:

I want it to look like this:


Try applying .navigationSplitViewColumnWidth.
I found it was important to apply it to the sidebar content, this being the List in your case, otherwise it didn't work. Then it really works - you're not able to reduce the size of the sidebar below the specified minimum width.
NavigationSplitView {
    List(ContentType.allCases, selection: $contentType) { value in
        NavigationLink(value: value) {
            Image(systemName: "info")
            Text("Some Long Text")
        }
    }
    .navigationSplitViewColumnWidth(min: 150, ideal: 150) //  HERE
} detail: {

}

Alternatively, setting a frame with minWidth on the sidebar content seems to work just as well. Then you don't need to care about the ideal width (which is a required parameter for .navigationSplitViewColumnWidth):
List(ContentType.allCases, selection: $contentType) { value in
    // ...
}
.frame(minWidth: 150)


If you don't like setting a fixed size then you can measure it with hidden background content instead. The hidden content needs to be built using the longest label being shown:
@State private var minSidebarWidth = CGFloat.zero

List(ContentType.allCases, selection: $contentType) { value in
    NavigationLink(value: value) {
        Image(systemName: "info")
        Text("Some Long Text")
    }
}
.background {
    Label("Some Long Text", systemImage: "info")
        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
        .background {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                Color.clear
                    .onAppear {
                        // print("setting sidebar width to \(proxy.size.width)")
                        minSidebarWidth = proxy.size.width
                    }
            }
        }
        .hidden()
}
.frame(minWidth: minSidebarWidth)

